# How can I estimate the approximation quality of the odds ratio based on a sample or how can I ignore infrequent items?

Tags: sample, odds-ratio, approximation

I am analyzing URLs found in tweets of the Twitter stream. I have two samples of tweets from that stream:

1. a random sample of tweets
2. all tweets of a subset of users

I want to find URLs which are specific to the subset of users in the second dataset, i.e., which are more likely to have been tweeted by the users in the second dataset than by the "general Twitter population". Therefore, I  compute for each URL its odds ratio, i.e., the ratio between the odds of the URL appearing in the second dataset vs. the odds of appearing in the first dataset.

Since the first dataset is a random sample, this ratio is an estimate of the true odds ratio. For frequent URLs this works quite nicely, but I assume that for URLs which appear very rarely in the sample data the estimate can be quite poor.

Is there a way to tell, for a given URL, how well the odds ratio based on the sample approximates the real odds ratio without knowing the real URL distribution? Or is there a method to compute a threshold to ignore rare URLs whose odds ratio appproximation is probably poor?

Update: Using [DOI:10.1136/bmj.296.6632.1313](http://dx.doi.org10.1136/bmj.296.6632.1313) I can calculate confidence intervals for large numbers. This allows me to discard URLs based on the confidence intervals, e.g., when they are too large or when the lower bound is below a certain threshold. Still, I am not sure whether this is a valid method to discard rare URLs.

Comment: (1) Sounds like you want a confidence interval for the odds ratio. (2) Note that the odds ratio is *not* a ratio of probabilities, but of odds.

Comment: Thanks for your remarks. I am now able to compute confidence intervals. I updated my question accordingly.